# How do I find & replace multiple values in Excel 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

Here is my problem. I have a large spreadsheet, about 3,500 rows and 10 columns, and want to replace a number in one column with a text value. Find and replace works fine for an individual find and replace but I have 16 different values I want to replace and on multiple files. I guess what I need is a macro or something that will apply the 16 F & R actions into one executable file.
Anyone have an idea?
Please be aware, I am not an expert on Excel, just an occasional user with a problem.

Comment: Macros are definitely your friend here, do you need to search for and replace all 16 values in each file? Are the numbers to be replaced also in other parts of the file where you don't want them replaced (does the find function need to search a specific column)?

Comment: I have been using 16 individual Find & Replace functions and I only need to do this for one column. I have never used a macro. I will research how to develop them. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Replace Genius](http://www.rlvision.com/genius/about.php).
[image: http://www.rlvision.com/genius/screenshot.png]

First you have to define your operation, in your case "Replace", and add it to the Preset Manager under the View menu.

Then select File -> Batch Processing, select all your files, and choose your preset to perform the replace steps on all selected files.

You may want to backup your Excel files first just in case.

Comment: Did not know about this, +1!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I take it Replace Genius is an additional application. I will research the add in as well.

Comment: Replace Genius did exactly what I wanted done. Took a little tinkering but in the end It worked perfectly!

Comment: Great, happy to help. Please accept this answer so others can see what worked for you.